# Querying mongodb date fields using $date syntax

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

In general using mongodb client console I used to build a date using `ISODate(...)` which works pretty well and is human readable. My issue is that I am using Spring Mongo Data and when I query some document by date field Spring uses a different syntax:

```
o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate : find using query: { "myId" : "1001", "period" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : 1577833200000 } } } fields: Document{{}} for class: <document _class>
```

When I use the same criteria on client console I always get 0 (zero) documents returned, although Spring retrieves the expected records.

Is there any trick to use the Spring Mongo Data query syntax on mongodb client?

When using `ISODate("2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z")` it works as expected

> unix epoch time 1577833200000 matches to ISODate("2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z")

Comment: I don't think there is a method in the shell to parse extended JSON into the original data structures.  For the date, you could use `Date(1577833200000)` in the shell so you don't have to convert to the ISO format.  If you want to do that automagically, someone would need to write a new helper for that.

Comment: @Joe Almost, it must be `new Date(1577833200000)`

Comment: Yes @Joe this is my main doubt because on shell I can use ```new Date(...)``` or ```ISODate(...)``` but not the same syntax exposed by Spring logs, although I bet the Spring Data would log something different than the actual query criteria. I saw a [blog post](https://zappysys.com/blog/how-to-query-mongodb-by-date-or-isodate/) using the same syntax but doesn't work at all

Comment: If you are protoyping your query in the shell, you can convert it for Spring using `tostrictjson(query)`, but I don't know of a way to go the other direction.

Comment: Hey @Joe seems to be the case, using ```tostrictjson(db.collection.find({ "period" : { "$gte" : new Date(12338575657484) } })``` I got the query output like this ```{ "period" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0100" } } }``` which seems to be how the query end up internally. Thank you for your help it's clear enough to me now.